# How to say "Be silent (or quiet), vexatious woman!"?

Tags: translation

Gonna occasionally say that to the wife :D 
Various translators have given a couple of variants, but the consensus might be...
Shizukani shite, ya shi josei  ni narimasu!
(where the "shi" has a long "i".)
Sound ok?
Arigato!

Comment: `the wife` <- So, she knows Japanese, right?

Comment: Are you looking for something with an old-timey literature vibe to it? Nobody would say "silence, vexatious woman" outside of a period film/book.

Comment: Yes, I was going for a comical-formal tone. No, she doesn't speak Japanese, and I only 5-10 words plus counting 1-10 plus "Namida dake ga watashi-no soba ni iru". :)

Comment: Do you mean いやしい (iyashii)?

Comment: Ah, did not know you were speaking to a non-Japanese speaker. You then might want to try しずかに、クソ女。(Shizuka-ni, kuso onna) said in calm and collected tone. The first part is soft and kind, the second is hard and abrasive but said calm you might get the humor across right.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that Japanese is not about using complicated words to express things. Just say "Urusai" うるさい for someone being loud or ”Uruse~na” うるせ～な to make it more directed at the person and also express annoyance.
More wording than that just confuses the point.
Also what you are saying is not something you can just throw out there at a whim, it's a mouthful.
On a side note, rolling the "RU" or elongating it changes the intensity from a casual "shut up" to more of an "STFU" (pardon my abbreviated French).

Answer (score 2):

One option would be: だまれ、邪魔臭い! (Damare, jyama kusai!)
No need to add "woman" to the sentence.
You can also use ウザイ (uzai) for "vexatious". 
It is a slang from the 1980's/1990's that is still common.

Answer (score -3):

One way to say “Be silent (or quiet), vexatious woman!”
in comical-formal tone is:

頼むから静かにしてくれ  うるさい女だな

> 夏目漱石 吾輩は猫である - 青空文庫
>   www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000148/files/789_14547.html
>
> うるさい女だな、意味も何にも無いと云うに」 「そんなら、品物の方もあとはありません」 「 頑愚 （ がんぐ ） だな。それでは勝手にするがいい。俺はもう盗難告訴を書いてやらんから」 「私も 品数 （ しなかず ） を教えて上げません。告訴はあなたが御自分でなさるん ...

> 坂口安吾 竹藪の家 - 青空文庫
>   www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/001095/files/45799_39317.html
>
> うるさい女だ」 「何言つてやんだい！ 又あたいの陰口だろ」 「お前さんは偉い女だよ――」 そして駄夫は構はずにスタスタ沓脱へ下りて冷い靴を穿いてゐたら、今度は台所へ引返して其処を拭きはじめた総江が、首を突き延ばして―― 「ほんたうに今日、重役に会 ...

うる星やつら（うるせいやつら）は、高橋留美子の漫画。

> Urusei yatsura (TV Series 1981–1986) - www.imdb.com/title/tt0081954/trivia
>
> The name "Urusei Yatsura" is a pun within a pun. In normal Japanese, the name would be spelled "urusai yatsura" (meaning "obnoxious people"). However, the title is spelled with the Japanese kanji karacter for "star" ("Hoshi" or "sei") making it "Urusei Yatsura" which could be interpreted as "jerks from Planet Uru," "Those annoying bastards from the planet Uru" or as Animeigo had it for a while, "Those Obnoxious Aliens."

i wouldn't call it a "pun within a pun" -- but the 2nd pun may be a star named 
うる星 -- as in ウル言語